# wp_get_nav_menu_items() with ACF

Tags: php, custom-field, menus

I'm creating a site with two menus. First menu (logo + page title). The only problem is my first menu I would like my client can be added his phone number and it is clickable and his Facebook link in ACF fields. I do not see how I could proceed and where can they appear? So I created a menu that I named (secondary menu) in `functions.php`, but after I'm lost.

I want to add ACF field in the items of my menu. The fields look good but how can I make sure that my fields are taken into account. I was told about `wp_get_nav_menu_items()`.

Being very new to this point I do not know how to go about it and found the logic with IDs etc.

```
<div class="second-nav">
  <div class="container-num">
    <div class="element-num phone">
      <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="element-num">
      <a href=""><span><?php the_field('phone');?></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button-nav">
    <a href="<?php esc_url("");?>">
      <button>Demandez un devis</button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="element-reseaux">
    <?php
    $social = get_field('reseau_social');
    if ($social):
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url($social);?>"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
    <?php endif;?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't they just add custom links to the menu? Why do these need to be ACF fields?

Comment: because these links are attached to picto